# Decimal to Binary converstion (fixed length) and reversing the order

Tags: perl, replace

I am writing a perl script which will generate string output of 0s and 1s.

I have numbers from 2 to 27. I want to convert them to binary number of fixed length 5 and then reverse the order.

For example, if I convert 2 to binary, it will be `00010` (fixed length of 5) and then I would like to get it reversed such that output is `01000`.

I am iterating the numbers through a for loop in perl.

What will be a sweet one liner or 2 to do this. Any bash or perl one liner or 2 that I can use in my perl script.

I am able to do it in 2 lines though but still looking for any one liner in bash.

```
for (my $i=02; $i <= 27; $i++) {
    my $j = sprintf ("%05b\n", $i);
    my $k = reverse $j;
}
```

Comment: I can use %5b in printf but again I will have to use replace function there.

Comment: Re "*`my $i=02;`*", Careful, that leading zero means the following number is octal. This is an unneeded distraction here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
say for map { scalar reverse sprintf "%05b", $_ } 2..27;
```

**Output**:

```
01000
11000
00100
10100
01100
11100
00010
10010
01010
11010
00110
10110
01110
11110
00001
10001
01001
11001
00101
10101
01101
11101
00011
10011
01011
11011
```